# Error while accessing NOAA CO-OPS ocean model nowcast on IDV

Tags: xml, metadata, netcdf

While using the Unidata IDV to access the NOAA CO-OPS ocean model nowcast for Galveston Bay via OPeNDAP:

http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/NOAA/GBOFS/MODELS/201302/catalog.html?dataset=NOAA/GBOFS/MODELS/201302/nos.gbofs_hsc.fields.nowcast.20130201.t09z.nc

I get an error message "error creating data source". It appears from their [OPeNDAP Data Form](http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/NOAA/GBOFS/MODELS/201302/nos.gbofs_hsc.fields.nowcast.20130201.t09z.nc.html) that many of the [NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Conventions](http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/) are met, but apparently not all.

Does anyone know what is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, there are a few problems with this dataset that need to be fixed before it will work in [IDV](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/idv/):

1. The Conventions attribute says "COARDS", but [COARDS](http://ferret.wrc.noaa.gov/noaa_coop/coop_cdf_profile.html) is appropriate for rectilinear grids (1D coordinate variables), and this data is curvilinear grid (2D lon,lat coordinate variables).  The [CF Conventions](http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/documents/cf-conventions) are appropriate here, so the "Conventions" global attribute need to be CF-1.0 or higher.
2. To be CF-Compliant, the "coordinates" attribute needs to be specified for each variable.
3. This model has a dimensionless vertical coordinate which requires the "positive" attribute to be "up", and sigma values to be negative, not positive.

Luckily, you can fix these problems using NcML.  Try creating a file "gbofs.ncml" with the contents below and load that into IDV instead of the OPeNDAP URL.  This approach will work with any software that uses the Unidata NetCDF-Java library, so it will work not only with IDV, but with [Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/), and [NCTOOLBOX for Matlab](http://nctoolbox.github.com/nctoolbox/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2"
  location="http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/NOAA/GBOFS/MODELS/201302/nos.gbofs.fields.nowcast.20130201.t03z.nc">
  <!--Change conventions from COARDS to CF-1.6 -->
  <attribute name="Conventions" value="CF-1.6"/>
  <!--The "positive" attribute is only for the z coordinate variable, so remove it from depth and elevation-->
  <variable name="zeta">
    <remove type="attribute" name="positive"/>
  </variable>
  <variable name="depth">
    <remove type="attribute" name="positive"/>
  </variable>
  <!-- Dimensionless vertical coordinates need "positive"=up, and negative sigma values -->
  <variable name="sigma">
    <attribute name="positive" value="up"/>
    <values> -0.1667 -0.4167 -0.5833 -0.7643 -0.9167 </values>
  </variable>
  <!-- Curvilinear grids need a "coordinates" attribute that identifies the coordinate variables-->
  <variable name="temp" shape="time sigma ny nx" type="float">
    <attribute name="coordinates" value="lon lat sigma time"/>
  </variable>
</netcdf>
```

I'll report this to NOAA CO-OPS and hopefully they can fix this in the future. Here's a screen shot from IDV just to show that this works:
[image: screen grab from IDV]